# Pandas Sample Based on Two Criteria

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     feature     target
0       2        0
1       0        0
2       0        0
3       0        0
4       1        0
...    ...      ...
33208   1        0
33209   0        0
33210   2        0
33211   2        0
33212   1        0
```

In the `feature` column there are 3 classes (0, 1, 2) and in the `target` column there are two classes (0, 1). If I group the dataframe by this two columns, I get:

```
df.groupby(['feature', 'target']).size()

feature  target
0         0             4282
          1               81
1         0             8537
          1               37
2         0            20161
          1              115
dtype: int64
```

Each `feature` class have `0s` and `1s` as `target` values, I need to find a way of sampling this values, my intention is to have something like this at the end:

```
new_df.groupby(['feature', 'target']).size()

feature  target
0         0             4282
          1               81
1         0             4282
          1               37
2         0             4282
          1              115
dtype: int64
```

I need to sample the amount of `target` values for each `feature` class, any suggestions?

Comment: Is this not already sampling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different distributions, depending on the value of `feature`.
You need to sample n value from a distribution, provided the value of `feature`: given that there are 2 possible outcomes, that is a binomial distribution problem. 
The approach shown below should facilitate situation when `target` is not necessarily `(0, 1)` - could be anything (*win* vs *lose*, *team A* vs *team B*, as so forth) as far as I can see:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# this is just reproducting your grouped end stated
df = pd.DataFrame({"feature":[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], "target":[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], "number":[4282, 81, 4282, 37, 4282, 115]})
df = df.set_index(["feature", "target"])

def sample_values(feature, sample_size):
    # select one of the distribution by feature
    df_sub = df.loc[feature]

    (event1, number1), (event2, number2) = zip(df_sub.index,df_sub["number"].tolist())

    return [event2 if np.random.binomial(1, number2/(number1+number2))==1 else event1 for _ in range(sample_size)]

print(sample_values(2, 100))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```